How to: resize entire page to fit screen size without distorting elements?
So, I noticed Letterboxd resizes itself according to the screen size without distorting any feature of the site.
How can I apply this to my entire page? They kinda just zoom in and out...


I don't have any idea of how they managed to do this, because for example, if I wanna customize my header I have to use display flex, and it automatically distorts the entire header when resizing the screen.

Letterboxd is using a HTML viewport meta tag to control the viewport width, you can read more about it here. They are using:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">


Removing the viewport meta tag will make that the browser wont resize your page.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
However, its worth to mention that this is more like a bad practice, you should care about your web responsiveness, also there is something named mobile first which basically, we start developing taking in care mobile and then the other devices

That is not what this tag with those attributes does. All it does is disable the DPR function on small high-resolution screens that have a factory-activated DPR setting. The rest of your answer has nothing to do with the things the OP describes.
